# Mongoose/Mongodb lookup nested array by comparing with another array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of ids and i want to look up in a nested prop in mongodb to see if any of those ids exsist.

The DB looks like this. alertDetails is an array and it contains objects, these objects have an ID filed and i want to check all those IDs against my array of IDs

```
  {
    status: string,
    openDate: date,
    alertType: [],
    severity: [],
    locationName: [],
    alertDetails: [
       {_id:5f0b4f508bda3805754ab343,
         }
],
```

This code below does not work. Returns an empty array

```
  let ids = [
    '5f0b4f508bda3805754ab343',
    '5f0b4f508bda3805754ab33f',
    '5f0b4f4f8bda3805754ab33b',
    '5f0b4f4f8bda3805754ab336',
    '5cdd5f00d5233209d7800c27',
    '5cdd568ed5233209d77fe464',
    '5cdd32d7d5233209d77f4bf8',
    '5cd58793d5233209d75f9d00',
  ];

  G2Alerts.find({ 'alertsDetails._id': { $in: ids } }, (err, user) => {
    console.log(err, user);
  });
```

This code does work but it's not what i want, i want to get back just an array containing the matches if any.

```
  G2Alerts.aggregate([
    {
      $project: {
        exists: {
          $in: [ids, '$alertDetails._id'],
        },
      },
    },
  ]).exec((err, alert) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    res.send(alert);
  });
```

Comment: You need to use the `$filter` aggregation array operator, within the `$project`. This will let you filter only the matched ids.

Answer (score 0):

if the type of alertDetails._id is ObjectId, try

```
const pmongo = require('promised-mongodb');

{ $in: ids.map(key => pmongo.ObjectId(key.toString()))}
```

Comment: it's a string not an objectid

Comment: try using $unwind to separate alertDetails(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html), it becomes {alertDetails : {_id: ..}}.  And using $group + $push if you want to make struct of alertDetails is array.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i managed to do it.

```
  let ids = [
    '5f0b4f508bda3805754ab343',
    '5f0b4f508bda3805754ab33f',
    '5f0b4f4f8bda3805754ab33b',
    '5f0b4f4f8bda3805754ab336',
    '5cdd5f00d5233209d7800c27',
    '5cdd568ed5233209d77fe464',
    '5cdd32d7d5233209d77f4bf8',
    '5cd58793d5233209d75f9d00',
  ];



const existing = await G2Alerts.find({ 'alertDetails._id': { $in: ids } }).distinct(
        'alertDetails._id',
        (err, alerts) => {
          if (err) {
            res.send(err);
          }
          return alerts;
        },
      );
```